# Cygwin shell add context menu item

Tags: cygwin, context-menu

There's this question on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637601/open-cygwin-at-a-specific-folder

I want to do something opposite. When using terminal I want to right click and have context menu item "Open Explorer here" to open regular Windows explorer window with current location (`pwd`). Is there a way to add context menu item to cygwin terminal?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out you can use `Ctrl + click` on a path in mintty to do exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

`Ctrl + click` doesn't work with my mintty, maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Anyway, I've learned some trick from [Pragmatistic Guy](http://oldratlee.com/post/2012-12-22/stunning-cygwin) and made small modification to accomplish what you want more elegently. I'll copy his solution here and all credits belongs to him.

- To ensure this script only run under cygwin, you may add platform detection commands to your `~/.bashrc`:

  ```
  if [[ "$OSTYPE" == "linux-gnu" ]]; then
      echo "Linux-gnu environment detected."
  elif [[ "$OSTYPE" == "cygwin" ]]; then
      echo "Cygwin environment detected."
      if [ -f "${HOME}/.bashrc.cygwin" ]; then
          source "${HOME}/.bashrc.cygwin"
      fi
  else
      echo "Unknown Platform"
  fi
  ```
- Now add following script to `~/.bashrc.cygwin`:

  ```
  function xpl {
       if [ "$1" = "" ]; then
           XPATH=.   # Open current directory in default
       else
           XPATH=$1
           XPATH="$(cygpath -C ANSI -w "$XPATH")";
       fi
       explorer $XPATH
   }
  ```
- You can now call `xpl dir_name_or_file_name` to make windows open directory/file with default program.
- `explorer.exe` won't block your shell input, isn't that perfect?